# Get Autofit Row Height in Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

**I am getting row height like this:**

```
var rowHeight = spreadsheet.Sheets[0].Data[0].RowMetadata[0].PixelSize.Value;
```

If you set the row height yourself, then this property will give the correct result.

If the height of a row is set automatically based on the height of the content in its cells, then **this property returns the standard height, not the actual one**.

**Answer: How to get Autofit Row Height?**

Write any ideas and suggestions.

Just in case here is the complete code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ApplicationName = "excel_app";
            string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };

            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                Scopes,
                                "user",
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }

            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest namedRangesRequest =
                service.Spreadsheets.Get("<<spreadsheetId>>");
            namedRangesRequest.Fields = "namedRanges";
            Spreadsheet response = namedRangesRequest.Execute();
            var namedRanges = response.NamedRanges.Select(nameRange => nameRange.Name)
.ToList();

            var request = service.Spreadsheets.Get("<<spreadsheetId>>");
            request.Ranges = namedRanges;
            request.IncludeGridData = true;
            var spreadsheet = request.Execute();

            var rowHeight = spreadsheet.Sheets[0].Data[0].RowMetadata[0]
.PixelSize.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tag has `google-apps-script`. Does your goal include using Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike, No, but through google-script-apps you can use google-sheet-api.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `through google-script-apps you can use google-sheet-api.`, I think this is correct. From this, do your want to achieve your goal using Sheets API with Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike, No, only Google Sheet API

Comment: @Tanaike. I removed Google Scripts from tags